# golang.org/x/exp/shiny/screen: Weird transition when uploading scaled texture in Ubuntu and macOS

Tags: go

I am trying to write a CHIP-8 emulator in Go using `golang.org/x/shiny/screen` for displaying video buffer onto the screen.

The original resolution of the emulator screen is 32x64 pixels. So, I enlarge the graphical view of the emulator screen by scaling the existing buffer by some factor and then publishing it on the screen.

Here's the code snippet for the same:

```
case paint.Event:
            log.Print("Paint event, re-painting the buffer..")

            tex, _ := s.NewTexture(dim)
            defer tex.Release()

            tex.Upload(image.Point{}, drawBuff, drawBuff.Bounds())

            scaledDim := image.Rectangle{
                image.Point{0, 0},
                image.Point{EmuWidth * EmuScale, EmuHeight * EmuScale}}

            window.Scale(scaledDim, tex, drawBuff.Bounds(), draw.Over, &screen.DrawOptions{})
            window.Publish()
```

Problem: This code works as intended on Windows but behaves weirdly on Ubuntu and macOS (gifs attached).

[image: on windows]

[image: on Ubuntu]

Comment: Possible bug in that library? Have you contacted the library's author(s)?

Comment: Not yet, I assumed it might be related to some bug in my code. The authors are Go lang authors, will open an issue on github